# Refreshing of shiny app in aws server when refresh button is pressed in browser

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny

I Have my shiny app in aws server shown here

```
 library("shiny")
 library("shinydashboard")
 library("pool")
 library(DBI)
 pool <- dbPool(drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),dbname = "demo",host =     "db.cr7lk1jwjdht.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",username = "kartik",password =     "12345678", port = 3306)

 mychoices = dbGetQuery(pool,"select available_scenario  from   scenario_name;")
  ui <- fluidPage(


  sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(

  actionButton("create_scenario", "Create Scenario"),
    actionButton("load_scenario","load scenario"),
   selectInput('n', "available scenarios", choices = mychoices, multiple =   TRUE),
    verbatimTextOutput("selected")

  ),
  mainPanel(
 uiOutput('tabs'),
 uiOutput("input"),
 uiOutput("inputs"),
 uiOutput("inputss")
     )
   )

   )

  server <- function(input, output,session) {

  observeEvent(input$create_scenario,{

    output$input <- renderUI({
     mainPanel(     
    textInput("txtInput","Enter scenario name"),
    textOutput("sname"),
                  actionButton("save","save_scenario")
   )

})


output$sname <- renderText({
  input$txtInput
})



  observeEvent(input$save,{
  #  conn <- poolCheckout(pool)
  #  dbSendQuery(conn,"insert into scenario (name) values (", output$sname   <- renderText({
     #  input$txtInput
  #}),");")
    dd <- data.frame(x = input$txtInput,row.names = FALSE)
 print(dd)
 dbWriteTable(pool,"available_scenario",dd,append = TRUE)
# values$dd <- rbind(values$dd,data.frame(Enter = input$txtInput))
  })

})

  output$tabs = renderUI({
if(!is.null(input$n)){
  Tabs <- lapply(paste("tab name:", input$n, sep=" "), tabPanel)
  do.call(tabsetPanel, Tabs)}

   })

   observeEvent(input$load_scenario,{

  output$inputs <- renderUI({
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
      fluidRow(
        box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

        box(
          title = "Controls",
          sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
        ))))


} )
histdata <- rnorm(500)
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
  hist(data)
})


 })
   }
     shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have a database table where i am storing the data for scenario name.
When i create a scenario named as Scenario-2 in server, it is saving in my database table but when i refresh the browser of shiny app it is not reflecting in the available scenario .
For it to reflect in available scenario i have to reboot the the server.
Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any code that is outside of the ui and the server will only run once when the R session first initializes. If you refresh the page or have someone else go to the app, the R session already exists, so that code won't run again. If you want this code to run every time the shiny app URL is visited, you need to place this code inside the server function. In your code, `pool` and `mychoices` are being defined outside the ui and server, so you need to move them (or at least `mychoices`) inside the server function so that it'll be called every time a new shiny session starts.

Comment: can you please tell me how to remove error  **Cannot allocate a new connection: 16 connections already opened**
error in above code @DeanAttali

Comment: @user11464272 Restart R.